# How to properly start the Photos app on windows 10 from dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

From my WinForms application I can open documents by using this code :

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    startInfo.FileName = fileName;
    process.Start();
}
```

Now if the variable `fileName` contains a full path to a `.jpg` file then in windows 10 it opens with some app called `Photos`
This works, but it has one problem I dont understand.

When I open the picture in windows explorer by doubleclicking on the picture, the app `Photos` opens and shows the picture. It also has navigation buttons on the left/right of the image. Using these buttons I can see the prior/next picture in this folder.
If I choose `SlideShow` it will show all pictures in this folder

When I open the picture using the code above, the same app `Photos` opens and shows the picture, but this time without the navigating buttons on the left/right of the image.
If I choose `SlideShow` it will show only this picture while there are others in this folder.

So my question is, how can I get these navigating buttons back ?
Also, there can be other file types then `.jpg` in the variable `fileName`.
I need a general method that will open each file with the default association set in windows.

In windows 7 and 8 this was never a problem, the navigation buttons always appeared. It only behave this way in windows 10

EDIT
If I have to use other code to open pictures than for other documents, I am willing to do that.
I can always check the extension of the file first

Answer (score 0):

You probably also need to set the working directory of the new process to be the folder that the image is located in.

It would look something like this

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = fileName;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunate the problem still remains